# Rails: Insert a full width div dynamically with JS in between rendering @trailers

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

In my app, I render a bunch of @trailers:

index.html.erb:

```
<div class="trailers infinite">
  <%= render @trailers %>
</div>
```

_trailer.html.erb:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 trailer">

</div>
```

When a trailer is clicked, I want to append an alert to the trailer:

```
$('.trailer').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.trailer').append($('.first-notification-message').slideDown())
});
```

Except my current method is messing up the formatting because it's pushing down only one @trailer column. I'd prefer to push down everything equally. But not sure how to do this because there are different number of columns for different screen widths.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put a row around each row so that when a column grows in height, it will expand the whole row. So loop through `@trailers` using `each_with_index` or `each_slice` to print the columns in their own `.row`s.

You can also make each column have a `min-height: 200px;` so it will always have space for what you add.

You can also pop up a modal dialog instead of changing the height of the column. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: Wouldn't each_with_index be pretty messy since I have to account for each different screen size?

Comment: Yes but that's how Bootstrap works. You could build it for 3 columns for the large screen, and if the browser gets smaller to trigger `.col-sm-6`, then you will have 2 columns in a row on the screen, followed by one column on its own row, but those 3 will be inside of the same `.row` div. It is messy so you might like to set the `min-height` for columns instead.  You might find something useful in this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll try the first method because making height set adds too much space